# Flask - session.logged_in not updated

Tags: python, session, flask, jinja2

I'm writing a simple Flask app, the first page will ask for username/password and check the validity, then update the session.logged_in to true. I use printout to check and the session.logged_in is actually set to "True". After logging in, there will be a html page that has a navigation to some other links, such as: Table List (which in the html file has the link {{ url_for('table_list') }} . However, when i use foreman and click on that link, the session.logged_in is None (not either True or False)

my python code is:

```
from flask import Flask, stream_with_context, request, Response, url_for, render_template, flash, session
...
app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True                # Enable debug-mode
app.secret_key = 'nosecret'

def stream_template(template_name, **context):
    app.update_template_context(context)
    t = app.jinja_env.get_template(template_name)
    rv = t.stream(context)
    # uncomment if you don't need immediate reaction
    ##rv.enable_buffering(5)
    return rv

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('signin.html')

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    # Read from the from input
    usrn = request.form['username']
    pswd = request.form['password']

    if validate_login(usrn, pswd):
        session['logged_in'] = True
        print 'login1:', session.logged_in
        sys.stdout.flush()
        return Response(stream_with_context(stream_template('index.html', data=genData())))
    else:
        return Response(stream_template('fail.html', code=pswd, username=usrn))

.....
@app.route('/listtable')
def list_table():
    print 'login2:', session.logged_in
    sys.stdout.flush()
    return Response(stream_with_context(stream_template('listtables.html', loginsession=session.logged_in)))
```

The result in the console is :

```
login1: True
login2: none
```

I think the problem is because I stream with context that somehow breaks the session that i'm currently have. Anyone has any ideas how to fix this problem? Thank you so much.

Work-Around: not sure what my problem is but I create new class call MySession, and in my session I have a boolean to hold a state of logged_in. By using MySession class I can update the current session and info that i'm currently having, not sure why Flask session doesn't work for me anyway

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), why don't you either use the decorator `@login_required` or if you need it in the function, then the method `is_authenticated()`. I don't think you should you're supposed to access the data structure yourself. Even to login, I am guessing there is a method you must call instead of setting `True` in the session. (You should use the `login_user()` method). You might want to go through [this](https://www.openshift.com/blogs/use-flask-login-to-add-user-authentication-to-your-python-application).

Comment: thank you for the answer but my goal is to learn Flask, so I don't really want to use any other packages.

Comment: What happens if you try to access it as a dict item, instead of attribute then?

Comment: I tried to print session['logged_in'] but it's still "None" for second print.

Comment: What if you try to print the whole session object? Can you put that here?

Comment: i have the first login1: <SecureCookieSession {'logged_in': True}>
, and second is a null object: login2: <SecureCookieSession {}>

Comment: this actually seems to be working for me, but what i don't get is how this `print 'login1:', session.logged_in` doesn't give you an error?

Comment: no i don't have any errors and my code is not wrapped with try,catch either. I found a workaround that I create my own Session Class and the value is updated on my Session class, just not sure why it's not updated when im using Flask session. Thank for your help.

Comment: It does give me an error. You set a key value pair and that isn't supposed to set an attribute. I'm not sure if you have the right session object there.

Comment: is it possible that you can update your working code on somewhere so i can take a look at? I just updated all my env, pip and distribute to the lastest version to be compatible with heroku, not sure whether that causes the problem or not.

Comment: All I did was this http://pastebin.com/Gy5wNBRi, I don't know if looking at this helps because I didn't use `stream_with_context`. But I did look at the source for `stream_with_context`. I don't think that has anything to do with session.